# How do I connect and use data from mysql database in a Vue.js project?

Tags: javascript, mysql, vue.js, mysql2

this is my first post. I never had to post anything because I always found a solution searching  in the internet or asking friends, but now im really confused so this is my last resource. Don't mind me if the solution is too obvious haha.

Im doing a Vue project (composition api) and I need to take data from my database, the thing is, that i just can't find the way. And I found that a possible fix to that would be changing
"type: module" to "type: commonjs" in package.json, but I'm not sure if thats ok in this scenario, and i can't find that exact same line anyways.

I installed mysql2 package and tried this line
[require mysql line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MLA0.png)
And after that got a reference error saying "require is not defined"
[reference error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXB0g.png)

Comment: You need a server-side component to communicate with the database, ie an _API_. There are **many** options for how you implement that but [Express](https://expressjs.com/) (with the mysql2 package) is a popular option if you want to stick to JavaScript

Comment: frontend <--talks to--> backend <--talks to--> database

Comment: There's also [Nuxt.js](https://nuxtjs.org/) which offers both frontend and backend integration with a Vue focus

Comment: If you don't want to build a backend - you can use Supabase directly from your Vue application. https://supabase.com/docs/guides/getting-started/quickstarts/vue